# .net cache size

Tags: asp.net, iis

Is there a way to monitor the size of the cache on your web server? I just want to see how much of my server's memory is being taken up by the cache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a [performance counter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxk122b4.aspx) named **Cache % Process Memory Limit Used** in the category **ASP.NET Applications**